# Get web data by using webclient or httpRequest

Tags: c#, get, web, httprequest

I want to use webclient or httpRequest to make request on some URL. It ok if the web don't need authetication, But if website need credentical then the respond not ok. I use example code of Microsoft like below:

```
 public class Test
{
    // Specify the URL to receive the request. 
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create (args[0]);

        // Set some reasonable limits on resources used by this request
        request.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 4;
        request.MaximumResponseHeadersLength = 4;
        // Set credentials to use for this request.
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse ();

        Console.WriteLine ("Content length is {0}", response.ContentLength);
        Console.WriteLine ("Content type is {0}", response.ContentType);

        // Get the stream associated with the response.
        Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream ();

        // Pipes the stream to a higher level stream reader with the required encoding format. 
        StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader (receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);

        Console.WriteLine ("Response stream received.");
        Console.WriteLine (readStream.ReadToEnd ());
        response.Close ();
        readStream.Close ();
    }
}
```

Who have experience about this please help me in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

HttpResponseCode has a property called StatusCode which specifies if the request has failed or succeeded. There are various status code which you can find online. But the one you are looking for is 401 which means unauthorized and 200 is for request that is successful. You can add following line after request.GetResponse() to check whether your request was successful or not.

```
if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK){
  // you can continue parsing your response here. 
}elseif(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized){
  // this means your request has failed due to authentication issue.
}
```